# Keep only numbers in text string and use to calculate total

Tags: jquery

Apologies if this sounds a little complicated, but I have a text string generated by my website as below:

`<span id="balance">£45.00</span>`

This is generated server side, so I don't have any control over formatting etc..

I'd like to use jQuery to extract the "45.00" - or even "4500", and use it in a math sum in jQuery elsewhere in the page, so, what I'm looking for is the method of just returning the numbers without the "£" sign.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have control of the server side code? If so, output a `data` attribute with the value formatted as necessary that you can use directly in the JS. This avoids any accidental amendments to the figure on the client side: `<span id="balance" data-value="4500">£45.00</span>`

Comment: Is the rest of the string always consistent? Or can e.g. the ID change? (And, to clarify, is the entire `<span>` part of the string?)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have no access server side unfortunately. The ID is locked in too.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove first character.

```js
const text = $("#balance").text();
const price = parseFloat(text.substring(1));
console.log(price);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="balance">£45.00</span>
```